# Why does google calendar have a BLUE background in jframe

Tags: java, html, calendar, jframe

When the calendar is viewed in a jframe jeditorpanel the background is blue and not white.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
public class ShowHTMLDocument {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      JFrame f = new JFrame("Google Calendar");
      final JEditorPane ep = new JEditorPane("https://www.google.com/calendar/htmlembed?src=groupboba@gmail.com&ctz=America/New_York&gsessionid=OK");

      ep.setContentType("text/html");

      ep.setEditable(false);
      f.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(ep));
      f.setSize(400, 300);
      f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

If you run this you will see the blue back ground, but if you go to the link in a browser, then it has a white background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems java jeditor doesn't like  CSS, so i gave up :(